# Println method doesn't work on second run

Tags: java

So my `Kiir` method doesn't work since my last run. The program should write the new values to a .txt file, and give it back the whole text with the new value included.

The program says the issue is in the

```
public static void Kiir(ArrayList<Versenyzo>versenyzok){
        for (Versenyzo f : versenyzok){
            System.out.println(f.toString());
        }
```

but I can't see the problem. Any idea?

```
public class VizsgaMintaA {

        static SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
       static Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         * @throws java.text.ParseException
         * @throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, FileNotFoundException {
            ArrayList<Versenyzo> versenyzok = new ArrayList<>();
            Feltolt(versenyzok);
            Kiir(versenyzok);
            Ujversenyzo(versenyzok);
            Kiir(versenyzok);
            Fajlbair(versenyzok);
        }

        private static void Feltolt(ArrayList<Versenyzo> versenyzok) throws ParseException{
        Versenyzo v = null;
        File f = new File("versenyzok.txt");
        try {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(f, "iso-8859-2");
                while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                    String sor = scan.nextLine();
                    String[] adatok = sor.split(";");
                    if (adatok.length == 3) {
                       v = new Versenyzo();
                       v.nev = adatok[0];
                        v.szuletes = df.parse(adatok[1]);
                        v.csapat = adatok[2];

                    } else if (adatok.length > 3) {
                         v = new Versenyzo (adatok[0],df.parse(adatok[1]),adatok[2]
                                 ,Integer.parseInt(adatok[3])
                         );
                    }
                    versenyzok.add(v);

                    }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println("Nincs meg a fájl.");
            }

        }

        public static void Kiir(ArrayList<Versenyzo>versenyzok){
        for (Versenyzo f : versenyzok){
            System.out.println(f.toString());
        }
        }
        private static void Ujversenyzo(ArrayList<Versenyzo>versenyzok)throws ParseException{
            Versenyzo v = new Versenyzo();
            System.out.println("Adjon meg egy nevet:");
            v.nev=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Adja meg a születési idejét:");
            v.szuletes=df.parse(sc.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Adja meg a csapatot:");
            v.csapat = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Adja meg a vb címek számát:");
            v.vbcim = sc.nextInt();
            versenyzok.add(v);
        }
        public static void Fajlbair(ArrayList<Versenyzo>versenyzok) throws FileNotFoundException {
            PrintStream f2 = new PrintStream(new File ("versenyzok2.txt"));
        for (Versenyzo v : versenyzok){
        f2.println(v.toString());
        }
        }
        }

       class Versenyzo {

           String nev,csapat;
           Date szuletes;
           int vbcim;
           SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");

            @Override
       public String toString(){
       return "Versenyzo:" +nev + " Született:" + df.format(szuletes)+" Csapata:"+ csapat + " Vb címek:" + vbcim; 
       }
       public Versenyzo(String nev, Date szuletes, String csapat, int vbcim) {
           this.nev = nev;
           this.szuletes = szuletes;
           this.csapat = csapat;
           this.vbcim = vbcim;

       }
       public Versenyzo(){
       }
    }
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

First check if the list passed to `Kiir()` is `null`:

```
public static void Kiir(ArrayList<Versenyzo> versenyzok){
    if (versenyzok == null)
        return;

    for (Versenyzo f : versenyzok){
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

I did make another change to `Kiir()`. 
I removed `toString()` from `f.toString()`, since you have overridden it, it is redundant. 
Now the only problem with your implementation of the `toString()` method inside the `Versenyzo` class is if there exist `null` values in the `szuletes` property. 
If this is the case then change to this:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "Versenyzo:" + nev + " Született:" + (szuletes == null ? "null" : df.format(szuletes)) + " Csapata:" + csapat + " Vb címek:" + vbcim;
}
```

Comment: Okay, now it passes `null` and shows so many nulls. But the `szuletes` cannot be null just the `vbcim`.

Comment: So what? It just show nulls instead of the values from the text. I really don't understand.

Comment: `vbcim` is `int`, a primitive type, so it can't be `null`.

Comment: If the loop works and the program does not crash, this means that your list gets null values.

Comment: Okay, so vbcim is a number in the text file. In sime line it's not in the text, so it can be an empty place in there. So maybe it's a boolean? 
Other hand, the program should write out the text, and where `vbcim` doesn't set it as 0. 

Now, since I typed the null as you mentioned, just nulls appears.

Comment: Are you sure that you are reading the text file correctly? Are you sure that there will always be 3 or 4 items and that they are valid strings, dates and integers? If not, your list may contain invalid values.

Comment: Okay, now I see the problem... It wasn't the `Kiir` method but the `Fajlbair`. It's overrode the text and deleted the splits between the values.

Comment: It should write the new values into a text file, and when it's done, show the new list. But that's not works also.